# Automatic Recovery of Virtual Memory Allocation

Tags: windows, jakarta-ee, tomcat, virtual-memory

My system uses a third part kernel built in native libraries (C++) with a J2EE upper layer running on Tomcat 6. The vendor stipulates 32bit JDK and overall the application very memory hungry. We are presently running on Windows x64 with 32 bit JVM. Essentially, the JVM will hang once the Virtual Size gets close to the 2GB 32bit addressing limit.

Question: From time to time, the third party frameworks will make large requests for memory and this pushes up the Virtual Size allocated on the server. The Virtual Size allocated will never recover even though it appears that the memory that the kernel is reducing its memory needs. In a typical Tomcat deployment, does the Virtual Size ever recover automatically or does it always act as a high water level that keeps on rising? Is there a way to tell the JVM to try to lower the Virtual Size dynamically?

I suspect that the 3rd party native kernel is to blame here but I need to investigate all our options.

FYI - AWE in Windows is not a clear option as the vendor does not officially support any JVMs that have AWE support. Migration to Linux is also not an easy path but is being considered.